# How to react to the glibc vulnerability as an OSX user?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, macos, glibc

Apologies if this question isn't really fit for this SE site. Wasn't sure whether to post it here, or on apple.SE.

---

What's the currently best way for a user of OSX to react to:

https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.nl/2016/02/cve-2015-7547-glibc-getaddrinfo-stack.html

and:

https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2016-02/msg00416.html

at the moment?

Several articles across the web link to the above and say 'patch now!', but they didn't seem to read the actual discussion.

From what I understand, several applications use pre-compiled (vulnerable) versions of glibc, and I as an end user don't really have any control over it right now. Correct?

So I'm wondering, is there anything I *can* do at the moment?